# How to run a CLI command from a Python script?

Tags: python, cmd, command-line-interface

When I write this in CMD (Windows 10) it's OK. The recognized text is in the clipboard:
"C: \ Program Files (x86) \ ABBYY FineReader 15 \ FineReaderOcr.exe" "C: \ Python39 \ Scripts \ abbyy \ Skan.JPG" / send Clipboard

I would like to do the same with a Python script to be able to parse the contents of the clipboard.
I am trying to do this using:

```
import sys
import os
def mycmd():
  os.system('cmd /c "C:\Program Files (x86)"\ABBYY FineReader 15\FineReaderOcr.exe" "skan.JPG" " /send Clipboard"')
mycmd()
```

But it doesn't work and you get the following error:
'C: \ Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I also tried using subprocess:
import of os

```
import subprocess
program = 'C: \ Program Files (x86) \ ABBYY FineReader 15 \ FineReaderOcr.exe'
file = 'C: \ Python39 \ Scripts \ abbyy \ Skan.JPG'
lang = "/ lang Polish"
send = "/ send Clipboard"
subprocess.run (["C: \ Program Files (x86) \ ABBYY FineReader 15 \ FineReaderOcr.exe", "scan.JPG", "/ send Clipboard"])
subprocess.call ([program, file, send])
```

But it also doesn't work as it should.
Please tell me why it doesn't work and how to do it correctly?

regards

Comment: Use `subprocess`. This replaces os.system and os.spawn*. https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 5):

Whitespace is important.

The space within `Program Files` is making that first file path be interpreted as two separate arguments, and it doesn't know how to interpret the first one, `C:\Program` as a command.

I've made a few similar examples to illustrate what works and what doesn't:

#### File paths that use no spaces

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system('C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\python.exe --version')
Python 3.9.1
0
>>> os.system('cmd /c "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\python.exe --version"')
Python 3.9.1
0
>>> os.system(r'cmd /c "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\python.exe --version"')
Python 3.9.1
0
```

These 3 versions are all successful because `C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\python.exe`, the file path in question, has no spaces in it.

#### File paths with spaces and \u

This command doesn't work:

```
>>> os.system('C:\Program Files (x86)\LilyPond\usr\bin\python.exe --version')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    os.system('C:\Program Files (x86)\LilyPond\usr\bin\python.exe --version')
                                                                            ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 31-32: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

because it contains `\u` (in `...\usr\...`). When you use `\u` as part of a string, python expects it to be a part of a Unicode escape sequence (e.g. `print("\u2019")` will get you a special apostrophe)

The way to fix this is to either escape your backslashes with another backslash (e.g. `'C:\\ProgramData\\...'`) or by making it a ["raw" string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) with a prefixed `r`: `r'C:\ProgramData\...'`

That gets us here:

```
>>> os.system(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\LilyPond\usr\bin\python.exe --version')
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
1
```

which is the problem I initially described; spaces are used to break up commands/arguments and cannot plainly be included in file paths.

The solution is to put quotes around the whole file path which contains a space:

```
>>> os.system(r'"C:\Program Files (x86)\LilyPond\usr\bin\python.exe" --version')
Python 3.7.4
0
```

These same things apply when the command is being sent as an argument:

```
>>> os.system(r'cmd /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\LilyPond\usr\bin\python.exe --version"')
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
1
>>> os.system(r'cmd /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\LilyPond\usr\bin\python.exe" --version"')
Python 3.7.4
0
```

#### Conclusion

So it seems that your line should look something like this:

```py
os.system(r'cmd /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\ABBYY FineReader 15\FineReaderOcr.exe" skan.JPG" /send Clipboard')
```

(though I don't know what the `/send Clipboard` part is for, and so may need adjustment from this. However, this should address the error asked about in the question)

Comment: Thanks for the extensive explanation.
The last command works exactly as I expected, i.e. it runs ocr on the image and copies the result to the clipboard.

Why is this code not working? (CLI)
set image = scan.jpg
cmd / c "" C: \ Program Files (x86) \ ABBYY FineReader 15 \ FineReaderOcr.exe ""% file% / send Clipboard
Is it possible to substitute the variable 'image' here instead of the name 'scan.jpg'?

How to use os.system and subprocess in this example?
regards

Comment: Check out tutorials for formatting strings in python: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-formatting-in-python/

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark as accepted answer